# try to display seven buttons with scrollview in a small screen

Tags: android, scrollview, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to put in my layout seven buttons in a small screen to test it (**Galaxy young**), So I used **the scrollview** but I still have problems (**the screen doesn't scroll in LandScape mode** ).

this is my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lieu_depart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lieu de prise en charge"
            style="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2_date_depart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Date1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/time_depart5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:text="Time1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="Lieu de restitution" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5_date_arrive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Date2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6_time_arrive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:text="Time2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*EDIT*:
**Portrait mode:**

[image]

**Landscape mode:**

[image]

what should I use to limit this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question it works in portrait but not landscape, so try this.  As you rotate your device it should still scroll.  I have placed this is in one Layout instead of multiple layouts.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView                         
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">              
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


   <Button
        android:id="@+id/lieu_depart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lieu de prise en charge"
        style="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2_date_depart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Date1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/time_depart5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:text="Time1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Lieu de restitution" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5_date_arrive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Date2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6_time_arrive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:text="Time2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

       </RelativeLayout>                    
     </ScrollView>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT...

You need to add the "android:layout_below="@+id/your button id" at every button so that the buttons will be displayed underneath each other..

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/lieu_depart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lieu de prise en charge"
        style="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2_date_depart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lieu_depart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Date1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/time_depart5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2_date_depart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:text="Time1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_depart5"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Lieu de restitution" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5_date_arrive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Date2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6_time_arrive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5_date_arrive"
        android:text="Time2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6_time_arrive"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />
```

You can then play with the layout of your buttons by setting the gravity and margins.  This should now fix your problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You must use LienarLayout inside of ScrollView. RelativeLayout ignores orientation and used when you want put your items with absolute position. Your xml layout has many things to change . Can you send image of your layout to understand what exacly you want.

Here you have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Starting place" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date 1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time 1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arrival place" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date2" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Time2" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In last linearlayout 2nd button i have include **layout_marginLeft** but with linearlayout gravity center it will center buttons and divide this space between two button, so you can manipulate with space between them.

By default layout will fill parent but in your second image you have something like right margin if you need it you can use android [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) but better way to not duplicate layout xml is using values-land qualifier and add dimens folder where you can add padding value and add to your layout into first layout child of scrollview **android:paddingRight="@dimen/your_property_name"**. More about [dimen resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: Ok I added the image for the two mode(Landscape and portrait). You can see it now.